# Amplitude of antenna-voltages induced by microwaves

Tags: rf, analog, antenna

I’m rather new to electronics and I encourage you to prepare yourself both mentally and physically for some very stupid questions – and some assumptions of my own (possibly very wrong) – about fundamental RF and antenna theory.

Starting from the beginning:

If I hold up a piece of metal in the air, AC voltages of various frequencies are induced in the metal and co-exist in the material.

Another piece of metal may also possess some geometric qualities causing it to resonate at a particular frequency.

Using the swing analogy – in the same way that a parent pushes their child on a swing in phase with the swing’s already existing pendular momentum, the intrinsic resonant frequency of the piece of metal constructively interferes the frequency of interest causing a small gain in the signal.

I assume the voltages induced by waves in, say, the UHF band, are of very low amplitude. What I would like to know is; which order of magnitude are we talking about here? Is it mV, tenths of mV? What would be considered an average peak-to-peak voltage induced by ambient radio waves at some particular frequencies? How much does resonance work to amplify the signal? How does RF-power output come into the picture (dBm) ?

Could someone point me to a source (book, article) that will help me understand this intuitively?

As an aside:

When I was browsing for some schematics of wideband transistor RF-amplifiers, many of the comments were phrased as if a 20dB gain was a great achievement – is it a great achievement? Or is it assumed that it will have to be cascaded to be useful under most conditions?

It would help to hear some empirical examples (unless I’m completely barking up the wrong tree) of what other people have done, be it Bluetooth, SDR or HAM – rather than just the mathematical realities (also appreciated, of course).

Comment: The amplitude of voltages induced mainly depends on the energies of the fields driving it. Put a CD into a microwave and then calculate from the spark lengths what voltages there must have been. Concentrate on one question to ask at a time.

Comment: Too many questions to get a full answer. Sorry but I'm voting to close. You are also soliciting opinions and this usually means the question gets closed.

Comment: Can I post a new question boiling it down? Which point I should stress more to not be deleted?

Comment: You seem to want all knowledge condensed into a simple answer, well there is none ! Understanding this all takes time, just pick **one** subject, for example antennas and read about and study them. Once you have a basic understanding go to a next topic. If you want to ask a question, stick to **one** specific topic and ask as specific as you can. For example: Why have antennas different sizes. Don't ask this question as it will be answered in textbooks. Also don't ask questions for which you can find an answer in a book or on the internet.

Answer (score 7):

It's not too complicated to calculate.

Imagine you have some kind of transmitter that transmits power equally in all directions. This is called an [isotropic antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_radiator). [Such a thing can't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), for a radio transmitter, but for the moment let's assume it does.

If this transmitter has a power of 1W, then for any sphere centered on that transmitter (assuming the sphere is far enough away to be in the [far field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field)), there is 1W passing through that sphere, too. The sphere must intercept all the transmitted power because there is no direction from the transmitter that doesn't hit the sphere.

Now imagine that the distance between the receiver and the transmitter is the same as the radius of the sphere.

The surface area of a sphere is given by:

$$ A = 4\pi r^2 $$

So if the receiver and transmitter are 100 meters apart, then imagine a sphere with a radius of 100 meters, and a surface area of

$$ A = 4 \pi 100^2 = 125664\:\mathrm{m^2} $$

If the transmitter were transmitting with a power of 1W, then at the receiver's distance, that 1W of power is spread over the area of the sphere. If we divide the transmitter's power by the sphere's area, we get the [irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance):

$$ { 1\:\mathrm{W} \over 125664\:\mathrm{m^2} } = 7.96\:\mathrm{\mu W / m^2} $$

This means if you had a "net" for electromagnetic energy that was 1 square meter large, and it was 100 meters away from a 1 watt transmitter that radiated energy equally in all directions, that net would intercept 7.96 microwatts of power.

But you don't have a net, you have an antenna. How big of a net is formed by an antenna? The answer to this question is the [effective aperture](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/aperture.php), which is actually another way of specifying the gain (G) of the antenna:

$$ A_e = { \lambda^2 \over 4\pi } G $$

λ is the wavelength of the radiation in question.

The transmitting antenna also has some gain (remember how an isotropic antenna can't exist?). If the transmitting antenna has a gain of 3 dBi, that means a doubling of power relative to an isotropic radiator. So the irradiance will be twice what was calculated before, or 15.9 microwatts per square meter.

So far we've calculated the irradiance at the receiver, and how much power will be received by that receiver, given its effective aperture. But you didn't ask about power, you asked about *voltage*.

Electrical power (P) is the product of voltage (E) and current (I):

$$ P = IE $$

Also, in free space, the ratio of voltage and current is fixed by the [impedance of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space), which is about 377 ohms, which means (by Ohm's law):

$$ {E \over I} = 377\:\Omega $$

We know the irradiance (15.9 microwatts per square meter), so we can solve this system of equations to get:

$$ \begin{align}
P &= 15.9\:\mathrm{\mu W / m^2} \\
I &= 205\:\mathrm{\mu A / m} \\
E &= 77\:\mathrm{m V / m} \end{align} $$

That value for E (77 millivolts per meter) is almost what you asked for. It is the [potential gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_gradient), meaning if you measured the rate of change in voltage per unit distance at one point, it would be 77 millivolts per meter.

But you didn't ask about the potential gradient. You asked about the voltages in a piece of metal.

Here's where it gets very complicated (I lied about it being simple). It will still be true that the antenna will intercept some fraction of the transmitted power. We can calculate the power intercepted by calculating the irradiance at the receiving antenna, and multiplying that by the effective aperture of the receiving antenna. And the ratio of voltage to current is the impedance of the antenna, whatever that might be. It probably won't be the 377 Ω it is for free space.

For simple antenna designs, we do know the impedance. For example, we know that the impedance of a half-wave dipole at the feedpoint is around 73 Ω. So we could do nearly the same calculations as before, but when we include the effective aperture there's an extra meter unit (remember effective aperture is measured in *square* meters), and that will cancel the "per meter" part we got when we calculated the voltage gradient. You'll be left with just a voltage in volts, instead of a voltage gradient in volts per meter.

That tells you the voltage *at the feedpoint*. You can also calculate the voltage at other parts of the dipole, if you know the impedance at that point. A dipole's impedance gets higher the closer you get to the tips. The power is the same, but if the impedance goes up that must mean the voltage goes up and the current goes down.

But what if you don't have a dipole, but instead some random piece of metal?

I'm afraid there's no easy answer at this point. By calculating the irradiance at the metal, you'll have some idea of how much power the metal might intercept. I say "some idea" because the effective aperture of an antenna isn't necessarily the physical size of the antenna. A dipole for example is a very thin wire, but it intercepts power from a larger area around the wire.

And we won't know what the impedances are at various points on the metal. This is going to depend on the geometry of the metal, among other things.

If you want the exact answer, you'll need to solve [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), which isn't so easy. Or use a computer to simulate the equations for you.

Comment: This is an impressive answer, Phil! It looks like the question will soon be closed.  You should find (or create) another appropriate question and put this answer there :)

Comment: LOL for the *it's not too complicated*, followed by 2 pages of complications, but +1.  I agree with bitsmack.  This is a bad place for a good answer.  Maybe you can ask a targeted question this answer is suited to so that others can find this knowledge.  You are allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: I would just like to point out that in Maxwell's equations, you actually use conservation of charge to solve one of the equations. So you'd need *somewhere* to both pull and electron from and put an electron, since the antenna neither creates nor destroys them. So that random piece of metal needs a (connected somehow) voltage reference. I also really like that example.

Comment: @Dave I suppose [displacement currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) can supply the "connection" you are seeking.

Comment: @PhilFrost, Well yes. But you'd need two things to hold the two different charges to create the displacement field. I ended up having a colleague point out to me that magnetic fields could provide a solution which doesn't need two things to hold different charges. This would still work in Maxwell's equations and means that for a single piece of metal, magnetic coupling would provide for a good antenna design and mechanism.

Comment: @Dave Two things, like the transmitter and the receiver?

Comment: @PhilFrost, That wouldn't be correct either. If you're moving the charge between the transmitter and the receiver, then those two things must be connected electrically. At which point you should just add one more wire instead of an antenna, since they already share one wire that you used to transfer the charge. A better way of visualizing it is that you've yanked an electron off of "M". Your hand now has a negative charge and "M" is positive. See, there are two objects, "M" and your hand. Put the electron back. Repeat those two over and over and you have displacement field between "M" and hand

Comment: @Dave Honestly I don't know what you are arguing anymore. If you have a transmitter, and you have a piece of metal somewhere around it (and not connected by any wire), there will be currents in that metal. That holds true even if the transmitter and the metal were the only thing in the universe, and as far as I'm aware, all of this is congruent with Maxwell's equations within the limits of classical electromagnetism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35939/discussion-between-dave-and-phil-frost).

Comment: You're missing the part of how the limit to the power / energy that can be extracted from the electric field at the receiver constrains the current induced for a particular induced voltage (line integral of antenna). Id like to see your take on that. It doesn't add up to me that any old induced current can arise (and it only be determined by the impedance of the receiving antenna/load) from the finite energy of just the E field, and how does the received power of both fields tie into this

Comment: @LewisKelsey Assuming no near-field coupling between the transmitter and receiver, there's no point to considering "both fields" separately because the two are inexorably related by [the impedance of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space). All we need to know is the power flux density at the receiver, and the receiver's effective aperture, and we can know how much power appear's at the antenna's feedpoint. Not "any old" current will arise: the current will be the one that satisfies P=IE (we just calculated the power) and E=IR (the antenna datasheet specifies R).

Comment: Yes. This appears to be much more accurate to me (effective aperture * irradiance) than just the potential gradient multiplied by the height of the antenna, which seems to be a common method in physics.